# Excel COUNTIF special characters

Tags: excel, countif

Is it possible to count specific special characters in a whole column?

I am trying to count all the commas `" , "` in a column and this is what i am using:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:D45, "=,")
```

The problem is that this only counts the commas that are alone in a cell. If i add anything else to the cell, before or after the comma, it will not count.

Examples of the cells that i am counting:

Cell#1:    `73(1), 210(5), 422(6),`

Cell#2:    `862(51),`

Cell#3:    `26(3), 156(6), 451(19),`

The expected output is 7
The actual output is 0

Comment: Are all those values in different cells or in the same?

Comment: Each row is a cell in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(D3:D45)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D3:D45,",","")))
```