# COUNTIFS and special characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data is laid out like this:

```
| User | Limit | Cost Centre |
| ---- | ----- | ----------- |
| User1 | <10K | ABC123 |
| User1 | <20K | XYZ789 |
| User2 | <30K | ABC123 |
```

I need to calculate how many individual roles, regardless of cost centres, User1 has.

I've tried `=COUNTIFS(Table[User],[@User],Table[Limit],"<")` but this results in zero.

Also tried `"<*"`, `"~<"` and still nothing.

I've also looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943628/excel-countif-special-characters#) which works to calculate how many `<` symbols are used (three), but I need to change the array to include only one User.

Can someone suggest the formula I might need for this? Thanks

Comment: If you are just trying to count entries by user, you only need one criterion, not two. If you need to count by limit too, use "=<*" as the criterion.

Comment: Or `"~<*"` which gives the same result, but better indicates the next character is to be read as value, not character.